# fancybox redirect when click on overlay not working properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

i have this weird error. I am doing portfolio website built on wordpress cms and I want to add fancybox to it. I want to do it like this: When user clicks on overlay in the gallery he gets redirected to homepage.
So far I am getting weird issue that redirect is working when you open the gallery second time. Any ideas?

```
// Activate fancyBox
$(".fancybox").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        }
    }
});

// Launch fancyBox on first element
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        afterClose: function() {
          location.href = 'http://povilasvaketis.com/';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should wrap all your code inside you Document Ready handler, to start with.